# Process ends without exception during asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Ok, so I got this little call to a public API using `HttpClient`:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
}
```

As soon as the operation reaches the `GetAsync()` line, the application closes without any exception, neither in the call stack nor in the event callback I've set up to catch unhandled app domain exceptions. I've already figured out it might be because `await` observes the executing task and supresses any exceptions, however if I remove the `await` keyword, the operation runs fine! What could be the problem here?

Comment: How do you run this application? Can you show the code that calls this method?

Answer (score 3):

You probably fire that operation without waiting/awaiting for that operation to complete. So the asynchronous operation is fired, but the application goes on and ends before the operation itself has had a chance to complete.

Simply `await` the root call (or use `Wait` on the task if you can't use `await` in that context).